# Attribute Comparison giving false matches and non matches in tinyxpath

Tags: c++, c

I am using tinyxpath-1.3.1. C/C++ on Linux. When I do a xpath search on a document I am not finding nodes when I think I should.

My XML:

```
<data>
  <event deviceId="25479545.5" interface="sensor-multilevel" 
         command="state" label="luminance" newValue="800" 
         oldValue="9" time="1412227484" />
</data>
```

My xpath Expression:

```
/data/event[@deviceId="25479545.5" and @interface="sensor-multilevel" and   
            @label="luminance" and @newValue&gt;600 and @oldValue&lt;10]
```

If I take the `oldValue` out and use `()` like this the comparison works:

```
/data/event[(@deviceId="25479545.5" and @interface="sensor-multilevel") and
            (@label="luminance" and @newValue&gt;600)]
```

Is there some limit on the number of comparisons?

Anything special with converting the 600 to a decimal?

Do I need to "" the value 600, it seems to work either way.

Any ideas on how to get it to work with the oldValue attribute included in the expression?

TinyXPath call:

```
TiXmlNode * node = TinyXPath::XNp_xpath_node( root, expression.c_str() );
```

Thanks 
Larry

Comment: What happens if you just leave out the `oldValue` and do not use parentheses?

Comment: If i leave out the oldValue and use no parnethesis, it fails to match.

Comment: I just tried your xpath expression on http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. It only works if I replace the `&lt;` and `&gt;` codes by `<` and `>`. Could you try the same?

Comment: The expression I put in the question is in xml encoding forof my test file that my program reads.  The actual strings that Tinyxml uses have the < and > instead of the &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Then it seems to be a problem with the XPath processing library...

Comment: Quite possibly, I was  hoping someone could confirm that or tell me I was doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the tinyxpath library has some bugs....

This works for tinyxpath-1.3.1:

```
    /data/event[((@deviceId="25479545.5" and @interface="sensor-multilevel") and
          (@label="luminance" and @newValue&gt;"600")) and (@oldValue&lt;"10")]
```

parenthesis were needed to group these in a final set of 2.

Or I just convert to using libxml2.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting a string comparison here rather than a numeric comparison ("9" > "10" in alphabetic order). That's incorrect according to the specs (both XPath 1.0 and 2.0, though they get there in rather different ways).

The safest approach is probably to convert explicitly to a number: write

```
number(@oldValue) &lt; 10
```

Comment: That is probably true if my library I was using actually worked.  But it gives me execution error when I try to use number function. I have a feeling that the library I use does not support it.

Comment: Sorry, I've now looked up tinyxpath and it seems it's not really xpath at all, just a subset of their own invention. Tagging this as an XPath question was therefore probably a mistake.